# Error in installing Virtuoso Conductor on CentOS

Tags: virtuoso

I installed the latest version of **Virtuoso** using yum on **CentOs**. I was able to successfully do that first time. However,when I restarted the virtuoso server after uploading a dataset/CSV file, I am not seeing the **'conductor tab'** in the webUI.

I thought something went wrong - and tried to do a clean install. But I have somehow managed to loose conductor completely this time.  Below is the log snippet of `virtuoso-t`.

```
10:41:00 INFO: PL LOG: Installing Virtuoso Conductor version 1.00.8727 (DAV)
10:41:00 INFO: Checkpoint started
10:41:00 INFO: Checkpoint finished, log reused
10:41:00 INFO: PL LOG: VAD_INSTALL: Please update server version (FATAL)
10:41:00 INFO: PL LOG: Errors where detected during installation of "Virtuoso Conductor".
```

Answer (score 0):

You report you "installed the latest version of Virtuoso using `yum`" -- but what version did you actually get?  We provide a [CentOS-specific guide](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSCentosNotes) which may now be outdated if someone has produced a `yum` package -- but that package may also be outdated.

Please check the version you have actually installed (output of `virtuoso-t -?` gives the best version string), and be sure it is at least [6.1.8 (if Virtuoso v6)](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews2013#2013-12-10%20--%20Virtuoso%20Open-Source%20Edition%206.1.8%20Released) or [7.2.2 (if Virtuoso v7)](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSNews#2015-12-09%20-%20Virtuoso%20Open-Source%20Edition%207.2.2%20Released).  If not, I would suggest a clean rebuild/reinstall, following [our instructions](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VOSCentosNotes), based on the latest source from GitHub.

For future, questions specifically regarding Virtuoso are often best raised on the [public Virtuoso Users mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=virtuoso-users), the [public OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/), or through a [confidential Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp). ObDisclaimer: I work for [OpenLink Software](http://www.openlinksw.com/), producer of Virtuoso.

Comment: @TheEvilPenguin I think you need to have a discussion over here: [Who watches the watchers?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262408/who-watches-the-watchers#comment52316_262417).